# Pexpect: Not able to redirect outputs to a file

Tags: python, python-2.7

Problem: Outputs from the device not getting redirected to a file.
Program: According to my program I have logged into one device and trying to collect few outputs.Here is the program.

```
     #!/usr/bin/python
     import pexpect
     import time
     import sys


     IP_Address= '10.197.225.226'
     Username = 'hey'
     Password= 'hey'

     session = pexpect.spawn("telnet " + IP_Address)
     result= session.expect(["Username:"])

     if result!=0:
      print("-----Failure connection")
      exit()
     session.sendline(Username)
     result= session.expect(["Password:"])
     session.sendline(Password)


     result= session.expect(["#"])
     print('success')

     C2=input('How many commands you want to enter:')
     for i in range (0,C2):
       C1=raw_input('Enter the commands:' )
       session.expect('#')
       session.sendline(C1)
       session.logfile= open("Result1.txt","w")

     print('Done')
```

Please help!

Note: I am new here.

I am using Python 2.7.6 (default, Oct 26 2016, 20:30:19)
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it myself.
Using a+ in open function.

Comment: Can you please provide your solution so others with the same problem can easily understand it...